# Flask session persistance along multiple subdomains and OAuth1Session

Tags: python, flask, oauth

I'm trying to use the OAuth token and storing it in the session object as I move between different subdomains. So I have the application starting the OAuth1.0a workflow at `flask.mydomain.com`. It then redirects to  `sub.mydomain.com/initiate` to fetch the request tokens and I want to save the oauth token secret using sessions (not sure if this is the best way), and then authorizes at `sub.mydomain.com/authorize`. Once the authorization is complete, it goes to the callback but the oauth token secret does not exist in the session. I'm also trying to save the `OAuth1Session` so that whenever we go to a new route, that data is saved. So I'm not sure how to handle it since the sessions are defined within the scope of the function.

I read that `app.secret_key = os.urandom(someval)` doesn't make it work which is what I don't have and I made the `OAuth1Session` to be global originally which doesn't sound like a good idea (happens in the callback).

```py
@app.route("/initiate")
def initiate():
    oauth_session = OAuth1Session(client_key=client_key,client_secret=client_secret,callback_uri=callback_uri)
    fetch_response = oauth_session.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
    oauth_token = fetch_response.get('oauth_token')
    oauth_token_secret = fetch_response.get('oauth_token_secret')
    session['oauth_token_secret'] = oauth_token_secret
    full_authorization_url = oauth_session.authorization_url(authorize_url, request_token=oauth_token)
    return redirect(full_authorization_url)

@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    session.permanent = True
    if ('oauth_token_secret' not in session):
        return "There is no oauth token secret"
    verifier = request.args.get("oauth_verifier")
    oauth_token = request.args.get("oauth_token")
    oauth = OAuth1Session(
        client_key=client_key,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        resource_owner_key=oauth_token,
        resource_owner_secret=session['oauth_token_secret'],
        verifier=verifier) # I would like this oauth session to persist until a certain amount of time before having to reauthenticate
    fetch_access_tokens= oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_url) 
    return redirect(url_for('.getstatus'))

@app.route("/getStatus")
def getstatus():
    r = oauth.get(webservice_url + "/statuses")
    if r.status_code == 401:
        return redirect(url_for('initiate'))
    print(r.content)
    return r.content
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, it was with the SERVER_NAME config for the application. The SERVER_NAME was set to flask.mydomain.com, so I just removed it entirely